# PagedListAdapter and ItemTouchHelper with Room - How do you update during onMove()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-livedata

The issue I'm having is that when dragging an item on my `RecyclerView`, the `onMove()` callback can not change the actual order of the array of items because that array is managed by `PagedListAdapter`. If I do it on the DB, this happens on a background thread because `Room` requires me to do that (and I really should do DB on the background thread anyway), and as you can imagine, that doesn't work well with the dragging of the item.

My understanding of how `ItemTouchHelper` works is that on `onMove()` I have to rearrange whatever I want to be shown visually and then I can save to the DB on `clearView()`. But I can't rearrange on `onMove()`.

This is a simplification of my current code, which works but the visual cues of the drag don't work well.

```
inner class SwipeCallback() : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
            val item1 = getItem(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
            val item2 = getItem(target.adapterPosition)
            if (item1 != null && item2 != null) {
                //BASICALLY JUST SWAPPING THE TWO POSITIONS ON THE OBJECTS but not doing anything with the adapter array because the PagedListAdapter doesn't allow me to modify the array as far I know.
                swapItems(item1,item2)

                }
                return true
            }
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
            super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)
            if (actionState == ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
                viewHolder?.itemView?.alpha = 0.5f
            }
        }

        override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                               viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
            super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)

            viewHolder?.itemView?.alpha = 1.0f

            //THIS IS WHERE I UPDATED THE DB, currentList is the PagedListAdapter array. This is an inner class of my PagedListAdapter.
            currentList?.let {updateList(it) }
        }
    }
```

So how can I make this work visually?

Thanks.

Comment: Just write a function in the activity that swaps the two items ...and then get all data again and submit the new list ..

Comment: Swaps them in the `PagedList`? as far as I know you can't modify the `PagedList` order without modifying the database, which I am doing but at the end of the move, not while the items are being dragged. I'm guessing that doing database work while the items are being dragged on the UI is a bad idea.

Comment: Why would you swap the `pagedList` just **write a SqlQuery to swap the values in those position** ( the positions passed from the adapter to the activity ). You need to pass two positions from the adapter to the activity. When the activity receives those positions. It triggers an SQL query to **swap** the values of those two positions.

Comment: My DB swapping part is working fine on `clearView`, the issue is `onMove`. For the list to look right while you are dragging the item, the list has to be updated on `onMove` but the list can't be modified without modifying the database.

Comment: You can add some `progress dialog` and perform the swap ( from db ) in `onMove` itself.

Comment: I think I'm not explaining it right. While dragging, you want to see the item you are dragging moving up or down on the list and items you are not dragging sliding up or down to make space for that item you are dragging. Without swapping the items on `onMove` then that can't happen. So right now with the code I posted, it all works except for visually I don't see any hints that items are sliding into the right position.

Comment: Do you need to use `PageListAdapter` since this is not a general purpose feature (rearranging items)? You could just query the data and put it in a `MutableList` and use it an adapter.

Comment: This is a for a media playlist, a user could potentially add hundreds of media items to it, that is why I figured `PagedListAdapter` was the right call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the right solution.

On `onMove` you have to `notifyItemMoved(from,to)` and then on `clearView` you actually make the DB move. Depending on what your move involves, you will probably have to store the first `from` on `notifyItemMoved` and then calculate where it is being moved `to` and modify all the times in between on your DB.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: [I created an example here](https://github.com/trunghq3101/LoadMoreDbNetworkPagination)

I assume you are using Room Database to load paging data to UI. In fact, if using Pagination library, that's the only way to make our list be able to response to dynamically change in data.

In adapter, you just need to notify database to change in onMove() function

```
    class SwipeCallback(
        private val adapter: HomeSpotAdapter,
        private val onItemMove: (from: Int, to: Int) -> Unit
    ) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            val from = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            val to = target.adapterPosition
            val item1 = adapter.getItem(from)
            val item2 = adapter.getItem(to)
            if (item1 != null && item2 != null) {

                // Notify database to swap items here
                onItemMove(from, to)

                return true
            }
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        }

        override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {

            // It has to be true
            return true
        }

        override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
            super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)
            if (actionState == ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
                viewHolder?.itemView?.alpha = 0.5f
            }
        }

        override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                               viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
            super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
            viewHolder.itemView.alpha = 1.0f

            // Don't need to do anything here
        }
    }
```

In fragment, we pass onItemMove lambda function to adapter

```
        ItemTouchHelper(HomeSpotAdapter.SwipeCallback(adapter) { from, to ->
            viewModel.swapItems(from, to)
        }).apply {
            attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView.getRecycler())
        }
```

To swap items in db, basically we can use a swapItems() function like this

```
    fun swapItem(from: Int, to: Int) {

        // I'm using executor to run query in worker thread here, but you can choose whatever you want

        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {

            val item1 = db.HomeSpotDao().getSpot(from)
            val item2 = db.HomeSpotDao().getSpot(to)

            // Swap index of 2 items

            val newItem1 = item1.copy()
            newItem1.indexInResponse = item2.indexInResponse

            val newItem2 = item2.copy()
            newItem2.indexInResponse = item1.indexInResponse

            db.HomeSpotDao().updateSpot(newItem1)
            db.HomeSpotDao().updateSpot(newItem2)
        }
    }
```

You can take a look at this class in Google Sample to understand how indexInResponse is used to keep tracking index of items in list

[Link google sample here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PagingWithNetworkSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/paging/pagingwithnetwork/reddit/repository/inDb/DbRedditPostRepository.kt)

Comment: When I modify the database on `onMove` the move looks visually ok for a tiny bit but then the item drops itself into position, I'm assuming as the Room DB change notifies the `PagesListAdapter` of the change. Are you able to drag the item past several spots like this?

Comment: Yes I tested those codes and they worked. At first I met the same problem as you, _the move looks visually ok for a tiny bit but then the item drops itself into position,_ That happened when I leave a call to notifyItemMoved() inside onMove(). Then I removed that call, just left only call to update database, so it worked!

Comment: Assuming you have a `observe()` on the database list and you call `submitList` in there, does that get called for you as soon as you do `db.HomeSpotDao().updateSpot(newItem1)` ?

Comment: Yes it must be called, if it doesn't get called then your UI list can't get update.
In fragment I did that:
`viewModel.data?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })`

Comment: That is exactly how mine looks. I don't understand what the difference could be. On the `updateSpot` method, are you swapping a position field or what? I have a position on my db and I'm just swapping those two on a transaction but doesn't matter whether I do it on a transaction or not. As soon as I drag past the first item, it animates as if it creates the space to drop and then it drops itself without me letting go.

Comment: I think because in your code, there are 2 places where you update something related to swap positions: one is `swapItems(item1,item2)`, another is `currentList?.let {updateList(it) }` 

Whereas in my code, there is only 1 place, it is `onItemMove(from, to)` 

That's the difference. I think there is something in your swapItems() triggerd this issue.

Comment: When I tested what you suggested I commented the swap on `onMove()` and `currentList?.let {updateList(it) }` on  `clearView()`. I then just added on `onMove()` a DB swap of the items. I'm going to see if I can find a sample I can play with to see if I can get this going and make a demo of the issue.

Comment: I added parts of your code to a room sample and I'm having the same issue where the item just drops itself. Any chance I could try out that functionality on your app?

Comment: I updated link Git in the answer, you can check here: https://github.com/trunghq3101/LoadMoreDbNetworkPagination

Comment: I am marking you as correct because your sample does work. It isn't as smooth as if you were updating a memory list but it works. However no matter what I do I can not get my test to work, I uploaded it here if you want to see if I made some mistake, thanks.  https://github.com/casolorz/roompagingtest